# Applying measure to a function

Tags: measure-theory

I was reading a paper, and they wrote $\mu(f)$ where $\mu$ is a measure and $f$ a function. I know measures map sets to nonnegative numbers, but I don't know what it means to write $\mu(f)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's something of a guessing game without having a look at the paper itself, but $\mu(f)$ is sometimes used to denote $\int f\,d\mu$. This notational convention is one of the ways people may use to express the action of a [distribution](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Distribution_(mathematics)#/Distributions) on a test function. Another common way this gets expressed is in the notation$$\langle\mu,f\rangle = \int f\,d\mu.$$
The $\langle\mu,f\rangle$ notation emphasizes the [duality](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Dual_system) between distributions (in this case measures) and test functions.